# Haskell library for 2D drawing

Tags: graphics, haskell, sdl

I basically want to create a full screen window and draw text on it in different colors and sizes (and also update the screen). I've used pygame for this in python and I'm looking for a similar library (should be fairly easy to use).

+1 if it handles input too...

Comment: Thanks for all the answers: I'm going to try both haskgame and SDL.

Comment: http://github.com/snkkid/LazyFooHaskell, http://web.animal-machine.com:8080/blog/2010/04/getting-started-with-sdl-in-haskell

Comment: So, after almost 2 years, what did you choose as lib, did you do anything useful, what was a general experience with 2D Haskell...?

Comment: @CoR: I used the SDL and the SDL-ttf packages from hackage and the experience was great: I managed to do what I wanted to and it's a lot faster than I expected it to be! Also I have a lot less code, doing the same thing now.

Comment: Thank you. I am about to do the same 2D thing, so it's good to know that SDL works well in real world :)

Comment: @CoR: No problem, I want to add that I've only used it on Linux.

Comment: Yup, that's the difference :) Who ever ported SDL to windows did opposite from nice and easy. Found 3 tutorials how to install sdl on win. None of them seem to work. Sounds like promising start, doesn't it? ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're looking for a specialized game library, you have a number of options that you can find [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries/Games). [FunGEn](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/FunGEn) is probably your best option out of those libraries. However, your question seems to suggest a game library would be a bit overkill, if all you're looking to do is draw text and receive input. In that case, you might opt for something simpler like [HOpenGL](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Opengl) or [hsSDL](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/SDL). There are also several other libraries listed [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries/Graphics).

Edit: After a bit more research, you might do well using [haskgame](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskgame). I've never used it myself, but it looks like it's got a few functions [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskgame/0.0.6/doc/html/Graphics-UI-HaskGame-Font.html) that do exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 69):

Instead of picking individual libraries, I'll have a go at a quick overview at all of them, as listed in the [Graphics section on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html#cat:graphics).

Basic frameworks:

**OpenGL**

- Part of the Haskell Platform
- Used for many small 2 and 3D games.
- Examples: [lambdacube-engine](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lambdacube-engine), [roguestar-gl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/roguestar-gl-0.6.0.1), [hpong](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HPong-0.1.2), [monadius](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Monadius-0.93), [raincat](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Raincat-1.1.1.2), [frag](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/frag)

**GTK**

```
cabal install cairo
```

- Used for high quality two-d graphics/vector graphics.
- [On Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cairo)
- Examples: [diagrams](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams), [4blocks](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/4Blocks-0.2), [gameclock](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gameclock-1.0.4)

**QTHaskell**

- Relatively little use, but when it is used, it is used notably.
- Not on Hackage, found [here](http://qthaskell.berlios.de/), due to C++ issues
- Notable users: [Nikki and the Robots](http://www.indiegames.com/blog/2010/07/trailer_nikki_and_the_robots_j.html), a commercial game.

**SDL**

```
cabal install sdl
```

- On Hackage, quite widely used for game-like, interactive apps with 2D graphics.
- Examples: [haskgame](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskgame-0.0.6), [Eternal10Seconds](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/package/Eternal10Seconds-0.2), [HTicTacToe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTicTacToe-0.2), [RainCat](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Raincat-1.1.1.2), [starrover](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/starrover2-0.1.1)

**X11**

```
cabal install X11
```

Venerable Unix user interfaces.

Examples: [xmonad](http://xmonad.org).

**GD**

```
cabal install gd
```

The GD graphics system. [Package on hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gd).

Examples: [wordcloud](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wordcloud-0.0), [sparklines](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sparklines).

**HOgre**

```
cabal install hogre
```

Bindings to the Ogre game [graphics system](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hogre).

Now, besides these game layers, there are many higher level frameworks and tools:

**Diagrams**

```
cabal install diagrams
```

2D vector diagrams (e.g. for math), built on cairo.

- Examples: [fractals](http://byorgey.wordpress.com/2009/01/31/diagrams-02-release/).

**Gloss**

```
cabal install gloss
```

2D graphics, very easy interface, relatively new. See TomMD's comment.

- Examples: [functional flocking](http://syntacticsalt.com/2011/03/10/functional-flocks/)

**Cal3D**

```
cabal install cal3d
```

Bindings to the Cal3D [animation package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cal3d).

**Chalkboard**

```
cabal install chalkboard
```

- [URL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/chalkboard)
- [Read the tutorial](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/csdl/fpg/Tools/ChalkBoard/Tutorial)

OpenGL-based combinators for generating images, used in teaching.

**TeaHS**

```
cabal install TeaHS
```

- [URL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/TeaHS)

A simple library for use creating 2D games, inspired by the [Ruby library Tea](http://tung.spheredev.org/site/node/82).

Comment: I keep forgetting Chalkboard has been updated to compile/run (it was broken for a while).  Good work Gill et al., and thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Great list! Gloss and diagrams look especially interesting and relevant to what I want to make.

Answer (score 16):

I'd recommend the new [Gloss library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss) as an easy way to get good results.

> Gloss hides the pain of drawing simple
>   vector graphics behind a nice data
>   type and a few display functions.
>   Gloss uses OpenGL and GLUT under the
>   hood, but you won't have to worry
>   about any of that. Get something cool
>   on the screen in under 10 minutes.

There are also [nice examples](http://gloss.ouroborus.net/), such as:

[image: hello world]

[image]

and a nice example building [flocking simulators](http://syntacticsalt.com/2011/03/10/functional-flocks/)

Alternatively, if it is vectors and text you want to manipulate, the [diagrams](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams) package on top of cairo can yield very good results.

Comment: Gloss is easy, but it's feature incomplete for anything beyond it's intended use of education.  I made a simple drawing application in Gloss and found that a few of its bugs (broken text location translation, broken window resize at least in XMonad, 100% CPU use when rendering in a Gnome environment, to name a few) detracted along with it's inability to display and translate images (ex: PNG, JPG).  This last one has been partially addressed, it can now display bitmaps.  To recap: I found Gloss really neat and easy to use, but it needs a few days of fixes and improvements to the library itself.

Comment: Is it ok for something really simple? I want to use it to visualize a simple roguelike. What matters most is bugless bitmap drawing (I'm going to use tiles).

Answer (score 3):

You could use Qt.  That's what the cross platform [Nikki And The Robots](http://joyridelabs.de/) is using.  You can see their source code and take a look at what they're doing.