# Pygame-like for haskell?

Tags: image, haskell, pygame

im trying to program a game in Haskell. Ive been looking for Game frameworks for that purpose, but i found a few and i cant make them work :/ . All i need is some image processing as pygames provides in python, like moving images, using layouts to put one image above other, and such basic things.
Do you happen to know anyone?

Comment: If memory serves me, Pygame isn't all *that* much more than a wrapper around SDL; have you tried just using the Haskell bindings for that? I also like the `graphics-drawingcombinators` package for a minimal, but pleasant to work with, way to get graphics on the screen. Here's a [very simple game using both](https://github.com/isomorphism/lazy-tetrominoes) I wrote a while ago. The code itself is kind of terrible, but it does show the libraries being used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Haskell library for 2D drawing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612201/haskell-library-for-2d-drawing)

Answer (score 4):

I was writing a library called [TeaHS](https://github.com/liamoc/tea-hs) which is something like what you want. It's old and potentially bitrotted though, and I don't really have time to update it. Fork it if you like :)