# Haskell Graphics Programming in Linux/Unix

Tags: haskell, graphics

I am interested in making a game in Haskell and I am looking for a graphics library. I found one called the HUGS Graphics Library but much to my dismay it only runs on Win32. I was wondering if there was a graphics library for Linux/Unix Haskell programming or am I out of luck. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raincat is a simple puzzle game written in Haskell that demonstrates graphics library usage and some strait forward techniques. Try looking up some Haskell SDL and OpenGL tutorials to help you in understanding the code. I am looking forward to playing your game.

Regards,

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Raincat

Comment: Woo, first fan although it won't be finished until March because I'm learning Haskell and had to decide on a final project.

Answer (score 4):

Do you know about [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html)?  Hosted on hackage are lots of graphics-related libraries.  Low level OpenGL bindings (openglraw, glut, hgl, glfw), higher level special-purpose GL libraries (ex: gloss), 2D libraries (cairo, gtk, gd), and more.  For 2D I suggest you see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612201/haskell-library-for-2d-drawing).